# XMPP ejabberd server is not able to connect gtalk server

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd

I have configured ejabberd server on localhost. I am able to connect to local host like admin@localhost, but i am not able to connect gtalk server. Some one please help me how to connect to gtalk server.

Thanks in advance,
sathi

Answer (score 4):

In order for you to talk to GoogleTalk, they have to be able to talk back to you using [Dialback](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0220.html).  There are several steps you'll need to do:

- Rename your server to a fully-qualified domain name.  (e.g. `example.com`)
- Open a hole in your firewall in **both** directions to your server on port `5269/tcp`.
- Add an SRV record to your DNS pointing at that firewall hole.  If your domain was `example.com`, your SRV might have `_xmpp-server._tcp.example.com` pointing to `10 0 5269 myserver.example.com`.
- At some point in the future, you may also need an X.509 certificate for doing TLS.

Answer (score 2):

I almost lost hope, but this [thread](http://lists.jabber.ru/pipermail/ejabberd/2009-January/004605.html) was really helpful:

Short summary - disable google apps for domain, it can be the reason of getting 404 errors in ejabberd log.